# Merge child nodes with the similar parent node, xml, python

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml file:

```
<root>
    <article_date>09/09/2013
    <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa1</article_name>
        <article_link>1aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    <article_time>0
        <article_name>aaa2</article_name>
        <article_link>2aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa3</article_name>
        <article_link>3aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    <article_time>0
        <article_name>aaa4</article_name>
        <article_link>4aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa5</article_name>
        <article_link>5aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    </article_date>
</root>
```

I would like to transform it to the following file:

```
<root>
    <article_date>09/09/2013
    <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa1+aaa3+aaa5</article_name>
        <article_link>1aaaaaaa+3aaaaaaa+5aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    <article_time>0
        <article_name>aaa2+aaa4</article_name>
        <article_link>2aaaaaaa+4aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
</root>
```

How can I do it in python?

My approach to do this task is the following:
1) loop through  tags 
2) form dictionary key- either 0 or 1, value - 
3) for each element in this dictionary find all child nodes:  and  and append them

Since that, I wrote the following code to implement this (ps I am currently struggling with adding elements to the dictionary, but I will overcome this issue):

```
def parse():
list_of_inique_timestamps=[]
text_to_merge=""
tree=et.parse("~/Documents/test1.xml")
root=tree.getroot()
for children in root:
    print children.tag, children.text
    for child in children:
        print (child.tag,int(child.text))
        if not child.text in list_of_inique_timestamps:
            list_of_inique_timestamps.append(child.text)
print list_of_inique_timestamps
```

Comment: what is your code till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution using `xml.etree.ElementTree` from python standard library.

The idea is to gather items into `defaultdict(list)` per `article_time` text value:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<root>
    <article_date>09/09/2013
    <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa1</article_name>
        <article_link>1aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    <article_time>0
        <article_name>aaa2</article_name>
        <article_link>2aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa3</article_name>
        <article_link>3aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    <article_time>0
        <article_name>aaa4</article_name>
        <article_link>4aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa5</article_name>
        <article_link>5aaaaaaa</article_link>
    </article_time>
    </article_date>
</root>
"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

root = ET.Element('root')
article_date = ET.SubElement(root, 'article_date')
article_date.text = tree.find('.//article_date').text

data = defaultdict(list)
for article_time in tree.findall('.//article_time'):
    text = article_time.text.strip()
    name = article_time.find('./article_name').text
    link = article_time.find('./article_link').text
    data[text].append((name, link))

for time_value, items in data.iteritems():
    article_time = ET.SubElement(article_date, 'article_time')
    article_name = ET.SubElement(article_time, 'article_name')
    article_link = ET.SubElement(article_time, 'article_name')

    article_time.text = time_value
    article_name.text = '+'.join(name for (name, _) in items)
    article_link.text = '+'.join(link for (_, link) in items)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

prints (prettified):

```
<root>
    <article_date>09/09/2013
        <article_time>1
            <article_name>aaa1+aaa3+aaa5</article_name>
            <article_name>1aaaaaaa+3aaaaaaa+5aaaaaaa</article_name>
        </article_time>
        <article_time>0
            <article_name>aaa2+aaa4</article_name>
            <article_name>2aaaaaaa+4aaaaaaa</article_name>
        </article_time>
    </article_date>
</root>
```

See, the result is exactly what you were aiming to.

Comment: thank you for posting the solution. however, there is an issue: in my data structure <article_date></article_date> wraps all other tags.

Comment: @mr.M ok, but I don't see the closing `article_date` tag..where should it be?

Comment: my bad. I have fixed the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write as much as I have time (and knowledge), but I'm making this a community wiki so other folks can help.

I would suggest using [xml](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) libraries for this. I'll use BeautifulSoup because I can't get xml to work for some reason right now.

First, let's get set up:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('''<root>
...     <article_date>09/09/2013
...     <article_time>1
...         <article_name>aaa1</article_name>
...         <article_link>1aaaaaaa</article_link>
...     </article_time>
...     <article_time>0
...         <article_name>aaa2</article_name>
...         <article_link>2aaaaaaa</article_link>
...     </article_time>
...     <article_time>1
...         <article_name>aaa3</article_name>
...         <article_link>3aaaaaaa</article_link>
...     </article_time>
...     <article_time>0
...         <article_name>aaa4</article_name>
...         <article_link>4aaaaaaa</article_link>
...     </article_time>
...     <article_time>1
...         <article_name>aaa5</article_name>
...         <article_link>5aaaaaaa</article_link>
...     </article_time>
... </root>''')
```

This just produces an internal representation of your xml. We can use the `find_all` method to grab all the article times.

```
>>> children = soup.find_all('article_time')
>>> children
[<article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa1</article_name>
<article_link>1aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>, <article_time>0
        <article_name>aaa2</article_name>
<article_link>2aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>, <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa3</article_name>
<article_link>3aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>, <article_time>0
        <article_name>aaa4</article_name>
<article_link>4aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>, <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa5</article_name>
<article_link>5aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>]
```

The next thing to do is define a key for how we define 'similar' parent nodes. Let's write a `key` function that specifies which part of each child to look at. We'll do some poking around to learn about the structure of each child first.

```
>>> children[0].contents
[u'1\n        ', <article_name>aaa1</article_name>, u'\n', <article_link>1aaaaaaa</article_link>, u'\n']
>>> children[0].contents[0]
u'1\n        '
>>> int(children[0].contents[0])
1
>>> def key(child):
...     return int(child.contents[0])
...
>>> key(children[0])
1
>>> key(children[1])
0
```

Okay. Now we can take advantage of python's [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function, which will group together all the children with the same key (we need to sort first). We will use the newly defined `key` function to specify how to sort, and what defines a group.

```
>>> children = sorted(children, key=key)
>>> import itertools
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(children, key)
```

`groups` is a generator -- like a list, but we can only iterate through it once. Let's take a look at what makes it up, even though that will mean we have to recreate it later. (We only get a single pass for generators, so by looking at the data, we're losing it. Luckily, it's pretty easy to recreate)

```
>>> for k, g in groups:
...     print k, ':\t', list(g)
...
0 : [<article_time>0
        <article_name>aaa2</article_name>
<article_link>2aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>, <article_time>0
        <article_name>aaa4</article_name>
<article_link>4aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>]
1 : [<article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa1</article_name>
<article_link>1aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>, <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa3</article_name>
<article_link>3aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>, <article_time>1
        <article_name>aaa5</article_name>
<article_link>5aaaaaaa</article_link>
</article_time>]
```

Okay, so `k` specifies what key was used to produce the group, and g is a sequence of the `article_time`s that matched `k`.

Sorry, that's all I have time for at the moment. Hopefully this is enough to get you started.